# Insert text in sg.Multiline from external Keyboard

Tags: input, text, keyboard, multiline, pysimplegui

Dears,

I'm wondering if there is a way to Insert text in sg.Multiline from external Keyboard ( Virtual On-Screen Keyboard):

it's working for sg.Input :

```
    if isinstance(element, sg.Input):
        if element.widget.select_present():
            element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
        element.widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, event)
```

And not the case with sg.Multiline:

```
if isinstance(element, sg.Multiline):
        if element.widget.select_present():
            element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST)
        element.widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, event)
```

I got the following error message : **AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'select_present'**

**The Remaining Issue :**
The above issue is fixed and once I want to delete characters from "sg.Multiline" it's going directly to "except" part , below is the script used. Could you please advice ?

```
elif event == "DEL" : 
try: 
element = window.find_element_with_focus() 
if element.widget.tag_ranges("sel"): 
   element.widget.delete(sg.tk.SEL_FIRST, sg.tk.SEL_LAST) 
else:
    insert = element.widget.index(sg.tk.INSERT)
    if insert > 0: 
       element.widget.delete(insert-1, insert) 
except: 
    sg.popup("Error")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `if element.widget.tag_ranges("sel"):` for `Multiline` element. `tag_ranges("sel")` return the range for the selection, empty tuple if no selection.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Yan, it's Working, Please tell me, any good refernce for the same.

Comment: Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python [24.8. Methods on Text widgets](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html), although it is for old tkinter 8.5.

Comment: Thanks @Jaon Yang, Still there is a tricky thing want to fix: Once trying to delete Character from sg.Multiline it goes directlty to except part ( Check above "The Remaining Issue part"). Please advice

Comment: Remove `try / except` block to show what the exception is and where it happened.

Comment: I remove it same result, but i notice one thing : I have created same script for widget "select_present()" and another for "tag_ranges("sel"), seems the script didn't take into account the one created for sg.multiline , it's executing only the one related to "sg.Input()). Can this info help?

Comment: Remove `try / except` block to show what the exception is and where it happened. Of course, it will be same result, but the key point is the exception information, not just failed and without any information to debug. Never just say it only failed to get help. The `index` for `Multiline` element is not an integer, but a string, like '`row.column'` where `row` count from 1 and `column` count from 0.

Comment: YES, Got it...Let me try to tune the same and update you.

Comment: No comment for it.